# How to make hover effect like these?

Tags: html, css

**I was searching some sites and i found Ultra-Host** [Ultra-Host](https://ultra-h.com/)

As you can see,when you hover buttons,they do amazing effect.
I dont know how to make effect like this one,i know just simple hover.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. **Describe** what you want to achieve, don't just link to someone else who has already done it. Linking to a commercial page also risks people thinking your question is spam.

Comment: They use _simple hover_ with a twist. Post the code you have and we can help.

Comment: Just simple hover `li
        {
            transition: 0.3s;
        }
li:hover
        {
            background-color: red;
        }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use combination of `::after` pseudo-element and `transform: skewX()`

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/JacobDesight/wuy3usv3/1/

Comment: I did something wrong.I applied this css and my hover is over my entire web page  http://i.imgur.com/gtgnMUS.png

Answer (score 0):

This is the CSS code from their site. Try it.

```
#background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(0, 81, 172) 49%, rgb(0, 156, 255) 100%);
  #background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(0, 81, 172) 49%, rgb(0, 156, 255) 100%);
  #background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(0, 81, 172) 49%, rgb(0, 156, 255) 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgb(0, 156, 255) 0%, rgb(0, 81, 172) 49%, rgb(0, 156, 255) 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgb(0, 156, 255) 0%, rgb(0, 81, 172) 49%, rgb(0, 156, 255) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgb(0, 156, 255) 0%, rgb(0, 81, 172) 49%, rgb(0, 156, 255) 100%);
  #opacity: 0.80;
  #filter: alpha(opacity=80);
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #00BFFF;
  box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 14px -2px #00FFEA;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 14px -2px #00FFEA;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 14px -2px #00FFEA;
  -o-box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 14px -2px #00FFEA;
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%) rotate(30deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%) rotate(30deg);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%) rotate(30deg);
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%) rotate(30deg);
```